# How to sort a list using lambda AND stream methods

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-stream

So I have an assignment to sort a certain `List` using the `Comparator` and using the lambda together with the stream method, and after that I must compare the time needed to sort the list using the comparator vs. the lambda and stream combination.

Let's say that I have a `Communication` class which has the `commTime` and a `Client` attributes (the `Client` has a `getSurname` method).
Now, in the app, I must sort the `communications` list using the two above methods. I've already done the one using the `Comparator`, but I'm having trouble using the lambda and stream method.

I have something like this:

```
Collections.sort(communications, (comm1, comm2) -> comm1.getCommTime().compareTo(comm2.getCommTime()));
```

This will go under an `if` statement (if the time is not equal), but if it is equal, I must sort the list by comparing surnames of the clients in the communication. I don't know how to do that, more precisely - I don't know how to reach the client's surname from the communication itself.

I can't do this:

```
Function<Communication, LocalDateTime> byTime = Communication::getCommTime;
Function<Communication, String> bySurname = Communication.getClient()::getSurname;
Comparator<Communication> byTimeAndSurname = Comparator.comparing(byTime).thenComparing(bySurname);

communications.stream().sorted(byTimeAndSurname);
```

but I have no idea what can I do.

For the part of the app where I have to determine the length of sorting, I know how to that, so no need on explaining that part (at least I know how to do something, right?).

Comment: It's unclear from this question exactly where you are stuck.  Are you getting an error you don't understand?  An incorrect result?  Some other issue?

Comment: `communications.stream().sorted(byTimeAndSurname)` doesn't do anything, because there is **no terminal operation**. You need something like `.collection(Collectors.toList())` at the end, and then assign that to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems with `Communication.getClient()::getSurname;`. Since `.getClient()` is not static you can't use it as `Communication.getClient()`. Another problem is that it would create method reference for one object which would be returned from `getClient()` at time of creating this method reference.

Simplest way would be using lambda expression like

```
Function<Communication, String> bySurname = com -> com.getClient().getSurname();
```

BTW `communications.stream().sorted(byTimeAndSurname);` sorts stream, not its source (`communications`). If you want to sort `communications` you should use

```
Collections.sort(communications, byTimeAndSurname);
```

---

Other way of achieving `A->C` mapping via `A->B->C` is using

```
someAToBFunction.andThen(someBToCFunction)
                 ^^^^^^^
```

([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-)). In your case you could write

```
Function<Communication, Client> byClient = Communication::getClient;
Function<Communication, String> bySurname = byClient.andThen(Client::getSurname);
```

Or as (uglier) "one-liner":

```
Function<Communication, String> bySurname = 
              ((Function<Communication, Client>)Communication::getClient)
              .andThen(Client::getSurname);
```